# BOOT_COMPLETED not called if device restarted using hardware buttons

Tags: android

I have registered a BroadcastReceiver called CheckReceiver:-

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.captchachecker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:installLocation="internalOnly"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".CheckReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

CheckReceiver code:-

```
public class CheckReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Check Receiver", "Captcha Receiver called");

        Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent service = new Intent(context, CheckService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I press the power button and choose Power off option, BroadcastReceiver is not being called.
If I restart the device using:-

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

then BroadcastReceiver is being called.
I have read about launching activity atleast once for BroadcastReceiver and launch an activity 2-3 times before checking.

Comment: Your adb command does not restart the device, it merely sends a fake broadcast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had used:-

```
adb shell pm set-install-location 2
```

in the past on my device. The app got installed to sd card ignoring:-

```
 android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

After I moved the app to phone it started working properly. To move the app to phone go to:-

Settings->Apps->Your app and choose "Move to Phone"

So, if your boot receiver doesn't works. Check:-

1. Permissions and intent filter in the manifest are declared properly.
2. App has atleast one activity and it has been launched atleast once by user after installing or after the app is force closed.
3. App has been installed to internal storage.

Comment: This is interesting.  Are you sure that #3 is required, or could it simply be that the actual install location doesn't conflict with the manifest?

Comment: For 3 from the documentation:-

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

`Broadcast Receivers listening for "boot completed"

The system delivers the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast before the external storage is mounted to the device. If your application is installed on the external storage, it can never receive this broadcast.`